# Как получить id пользователя, запустившего процесс в C# .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Как можно получить id пользователя процесса (не текущего)?
Получаю список процессов через Process.GetProcesses, и нужно получить id пользователей процесса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы имели ввиду имя пользователя то его можно получит с помощью пакета [System.Managment](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/)

```
 public static string GetProcessOwner(int processId)
    {
        string query = "Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessID = " + processId;
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        ManagementObjectCollection processList = searcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject obj in processList)
        {
            string[] argList = new string[] { string.Empty, string.Empty };
            int returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(obj.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList));
            if (returnVal == 0)
            {
                return argList[0];
            }
        }

        return "NO OWNER";
    }
```

Получит SID от имя пользователя

```
     static string GetSidFromUserName(string username)
    {
        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
          new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
          $"SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount where name='{username}'");
            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                return queryObj["SID"].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Оброботка ошибки
        }
        return "";
    }
```

И получит через  процесс :

```
 var process = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (var item in process)
        {
           var user = GetProcessOwner(item.Id);
            var userId = GetSidFromUserName(user);
        }
```

Comment: Нет, именно id пользователя, имя я уже получил, но id тоже нужен

Comment: @eSkry Какой Id? ну разве что на ASP.NET?

Comment: @Dllshod id, sid, guid что на винде индентификатором служит? на линуксе есть имя пользователя и есть id пользователя, мне нужно аналогично имя и идентификатор на винде получить

Comment: @eSkry Изминил код